# Удаление элемента. Односвязный список

Tags: c++, списки, односвязный-список

Функция foundel(List*&,int) совершает удаление n-го элемента, работает неправильно, знаю в чем ошибка, но исправить не получается.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct List {
    int x;
    List *next;
};

void buildlist(List **lst, int n) {

    List *ptr = *lst;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        List *tmp = new List;
        cin >> tmp->x;
        tmp->next = (*lst);
        (*lst) = tmp;
    }
}

void print(List *lst) {
    cout << endl;
    while (lst) {
        cout << lst->x << ' ';
        lst = lst->next;
    }
}

void foundel(List *&lst, int n) {
    List *ptr = lst;
    List *temp = lst;

    while (n--) {
        ptr = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    ptr->next = temp->next;
    delete temp;
}

void del(List *&lst) {
    List *pdel = lst;
    while (lst) {
        lst = lst->next;
        delete pdel;
        pdel = lst;
    }
}

int main()  {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    List *lst, *beg;
    int n = 0, f = 0;
    beg = lst = NULL;

    cout << "Введите размер списка: "; cin >> n;
    buildlist(&lst, n);

    print(lst);

    cout << "\n=================" << endl
        << "Какой элемент хотите удалить(посчету): ";
    cin >> f;
    foundel(lst, f);

    print(lst);

    del(lst);
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void foundel(List *&lst, int n) 
{
  List **pnext = &lst;

  for (; n > 1; --n)
    pnext = &(*pnext)->next;

  List *todel = *pnext;
  *pnext = todel->next;

  delete todel;
}
```

Разумеется, нужно еще учитывать возможность возникновения нештатных ситуаций.

Answer (score 0):

Вот я исправил, но скорее это какой-то подогнанный вариант, если есть более грамотная запись, хочется посмотреть

```
void foundel(List *&lst, int n) {
    List *ptr = lst;
    List *temp = lst;

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        ptr = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    if (n == 1)
        lst = lst->next;

    ptr->next = temp->next;
    delete temp;
}
```